# C# string with shared library

Tags: c#, .net, go, ffi

I have a shared library built with Go and a program in C# that I want to call the function in the shared library. But prints an empty line.

This is the C# code:

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    [DllImport("./main.so", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    static extern void Println(string s);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Println("hello world");
    }
}
```

This the Go code:

```golang
package main

import "C"
import "fmt"

//export Println
func Println(s string){
    fmt.Println(s)
}

func main(){}
```

How I can pass the C# string as a Go string?

Comment: use `Println(s *C.char)` on the Go side (and then `C.GoString(s)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem

The problem is that while `-buildmode=c-shared` (and `-buildmode=c-whatever` in general) do indeed make the Go symbols callable from C, this comes with a twist when it comes to strings.

In C, there really is no such thing as a string but a convention exists that a string is a pointer to its first byte, and the length of a string is *implicitly* defined by a byte with code 0 (ASCII `NUL`) in that string.

In Go, strings are `struct`s of two fields: a pointer to a memory block containing the string's contents and the number of bytes in that block.

As you can see, when the Go toolset compiles a Go function marked as "exported to C", it basically has two choices:

- Make the function callable "as is"—requiring the callers to pass a Go-style `struct` value describing a string.
- Artifically "wrap" the exported function into a code block which would take a "C-style" NUL-terminated string, count the number of bytes in it, cook a Go-style `struct` value and finally call the original function.

The second approach could arguably be simpler for non-Go programmers to deal with but there exist two arguments against using it:

- This approach incurs hidden cost for each call: scanning the bytes of the string—even if the caller knows it.
- It's possible—if needed—to create such a wrapper right in the Go code—as @Selvin suggested in their comment to the question.

So, to reiterate, when the Go toolset compiles a Go function marked as "exported to C" in a `c-whatever` mode, it follows the Go convention and the result of its work is:

- The compiled library expects to receive a `struct`-typed value comprised of a pointer and a size—as described above—for each argument of Go type `string` of each exported function.
- The supporting C header file is be generated, containing the definition of that `struct` type—it will be called `GoString`,—and a declaration for all your exported functions, using that `GoString` type for the arguments which are `string` on the Go side.

To say it in more simple words, if you were to create a file `foo.go` containing

```golang
package main

import "C"

import "fmt"

//export PrintIt
func PrintIt(string s) {
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

and were then compile it using `go build -buildmode=c-shared -o foo.so foo.go`,
the Go toolset would create both `foo.so` and `foo.h`, containing—among other things—somethig like:

```
typedef struct { const char *p; ptrdiff_t n; } GoString;

extern void PrintIt(GoString p0);
```

As you can see, to call `PrintIt`, you're supposed to pass it an instance of `GoString`, not a value of type `const char *`.

### A solution

A proper solution is to have something like

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=0)]
struct GoString {
    byte *p;
    int  n;
}
```

And then

```
[DllImport("./main.so", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern void Println(GoString gs);
```

Note that I'm not quite sure plain `int` is OK to be used for `ptrdiff_t` in each and every case—please do your own research on what should be properly be used for in in .NET interop.

Comment: On a side note, it _may_ be useful to keep in mind that in some circumstances Go _assumes_ its strings are encoded in UTF-8—such as when iterating over a string using the `for ... range` statement; so you might consider specifying another charset for the interop if you're supposed to pass strings which may contain Unicode characters outside of the ASCII subset.

Comment: you may replace `byte *p;` with `string p;` with `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPUTF8Str)` attribute